# Truffle Console: Can't 'transfer' Ether from one SC to another

Tags: solidity, truffle, transfer

I am trying to execute the following sender SC to send funds to the receiver SC below it:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;
contract OwnableWallet {//sender
address payable owner;
// called by the constructor
function initWallet(address payable _owner) public {
   owner = _owner; // any user can change owner
   // more setup
}            
// allows the owner to withdraw ether
function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
   if (msg.sender == owner) {
      owner.transfer(_amount);
  }
}
function() external payable{}
}
```

==Receiver Smart Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;
contract TxUserWalletAtt {//receiver
   uint public  count;
   address owner;
   constructor() public {
       owner = msg.sender;
   }
   function() external payable  {  
  }
}
```

==Below is the Truffle script

```
$ truffle console
truffle(development)> const acc2= accounts[2]
undefined
truffle(development)> acc2bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(acc2)
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.utils.fromWei(acc2bal, "ether")
'44.997896'
truffle(development)> OW = await OwnableWallet.new()
undefined
truffle(development)> OWbal = await web3.eth.getBalance(OW.address)
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.utils.fromWei(OWbal, "ether")
'0'
truffle(development)> options = {from: acc2, to : OW.address, value: web3.utils.toWei('11', 'ether')}
{ from: '0xc7B89453Ba9902C4aD41f47c0324b36ccc347d2E',
 to: '0xA4d07c85aB3238Ed17F7f5311B9F4DF95b85f3b1',
 value: '11000000000000000000' }
truffle(development)> OW.sendTransaction(options)
{ tx:
  '0x6d64b18a4354828ee9d2e5fd785cee08fecb4c6415e1a70ecca4ec0bffe3d364',
 receipt:
  { transactionHash:
     '0x6d64b18a4354828ee9d2e5fd785cee08fecb4c6415e1a70ecca4ec0bffe3d364',
truffle(development)> OWbal = await web3.eth.getBalance(OW.address)
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.utils.fromWei(OWbal, "ether")
'11'
```

Sender has 11 Ether, now receiver

```
truffle(development)> TX = await TxUserWalletAtt.new()
undefined
truffle(development)> TXBal = await web3.eth.getBalance(TX.address)//
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.utils.fromWei(TXBal, "ether")
'0'
Executing initWallet(..) method of sender
truffle(development)> arg1 = TX.address
'0xF8E4d4d7254a6dA91Cc9A910B876123cA1A3A52f'
truffle(development)> await OW.initWallet(arg1)
{ tx:
  '0xabf5ed781799e6cdcb9bcc0864c6b5785c825d45158a7a8c6dc39115d2643e2b',
 receipt:
  { transactionHash:
     '0xabf5ed781799e6cdcb9bcc0864c6b5785c825d45158a7a8c6dc39115d2643e2b',
```

Now executing the transfer method withdraw(..)

```
  truffle(development)> arg2 = '6' //Note I tried with integer also
        '6'
        truffle(development)> await OW.withdraw(arg2)
        { tx:
          '0x83099adea1970040ee2252c622e121828d4320f79090c3a8129594feec7328f6',
         receipt:
          { transactionHash:
             '0x83099adea1970040ee2252c622e121828d4320f79090c3a8129594feec7328f6',
            transactionIndex: 0,
```

Now displaying the balance which are same as before sending:

```
truffle(development)> TXBal = await web3.eth.getBalance(TX.address)
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.utils.fromWei(TXBal, "ether")
'0'
truffle(development)> OWbal = await web3.eth.getBalance(OW.address)
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.utils.fromWei(OWbal, "ether")
'11'
truffle(development)> arg2 = 6//Againwith integer value
6
truffle(development)> await OW.withdraw(arg2)
{ tx:
  '0x62fa25a4581960cc98bb415e9178cd7d485aa8722fb09f74999fb1b5f825eea3',
 receipt:
  { transactionHash:
     '0x62fa25a4581960cc98bb415e9178cd7d485aa8722fb09f74999fb1b5f825eea3',
    transactionIndex: 0,
```

Now displaying the balances:

```
truffle(development)> OWbal = await web3.eth.getBalance(OW.address)
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.utils.fromWei(OWbal, "ether")
'11'
truffle(development)> 
truffle(development)> attBal = await web3.eth.getBalance(att.address)
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.utils.fromWei(attBal, "ether")
'0'
```

Somebody guide why the Ether is not received by the receiver and why the victim balance is the same after transfer.
Zulfi.

Answer (score 0):

Owner should be a payable address in your case.

I suggest you use the receive function to allow the contracts to receive ether and update your solidity version.

You should call the recipient with a message

```
owner().call{value: _amount}("")

//or

payable(owner).transfer(_amount);

receive() external payable{
        // this contract can receive ether
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I am using version 5 which does not use receive. Tell me a version 5-related solution. Zulfi.